# "How would you remove an element from a Ruby array that is just another element reversed?"

Tags: arrays, ruby, duplicates

I need to remove a reversed word from a Ruby array and I'm having issues with getting the correct output

I've tried a different way of looping, I've used exec.

````
# Were going to get the first line of input which is the length of the wordlist and coerce to type fixnum
pword_list_length = gets.chomp.to_i

# Initialize an empty array to hold pword_list_length
pword_list = Array.new

# loop until we have all the lines of input pushed into the array
pword_list_length.times do
pword_list.push(gets.chomp)
end

# Next were going to check to see what word we have both forward and backwards
pword_list.each do |word|
bword = word.reverse!
  if pword_list.include? bword 
    print word.length
    print bword[bword.length/2]

  end
end```

```Expected Output:
3 y

Output
3y3c3e3y```
````

Comment: Can you please tell us both – example input and the expected output.

Comment: Please, make sure to provide a [mre]. Your example is neither minimal (what do the first 12 lines have to do with removing an element from an array?) nor reproducible (it relies on external input that you are not showing us).

Answer (score 0):

You are mutating list here:

```
bword = word.reverse!
```

`reverse!` will actually reverse content of variable `word`. After that list will sure include `bword` as you just made `word` reversed and assigned it to `bword`.

Use `reverse` (without !) to keep `word` unchanged.

Comment: Problem Description:
Ethan has a possible list of password to hack a secure account. To select the correct password, he researched the owner and discovered that the account's owner is very fond of acronyms. After eliminating the rest of the patterns, Ethan is now sure that the password and its reverse, both, are present in the list. You need to find the password among that list and print its length along with its middlemost character.
NOTE: All strings in the list are of odd length.

Comment: Above is the coding prompt. I have gotten to the point of having the list. I just need to remove the reversed string from the list, thats what I'm having issues doing. The expected output for the first test case is ```3 y```

Comment: Just try to replace `reverse!` with 'reverse'. Or provide test case data.